# QuickFix Market Data Request Error

Tags: c#, quickfix, fix-protocol

I am new to fix. I am using  `quickfix` library in my app. I'm able to do logon and exchange heart beat. But when i send the market data request, i get the below error.

```
8=FIX.4.49=13035=V34=249=PrimoDEMOFIX52=20160622-17:35:14.62256=CfhDemoPrices262=PrimoApp123263=1264=0265=0269=0146=155=GBPUSD267=110=129
8=FIX.4.49=14435=334=249=CfhDemoPrices52=20160622-17:35:18.36756=PrimoDEMOFIX45=258=Incorrect NumInGroup count for repeating group371=267372=V373=1610=043
```

Below is the code where is generate the message.

```
Message msg = new Message();
QuickFix.FIX44.MarketDataRequest.NoRelatedSymGroup group = new QuickFix.FIX44.MarketDataRequest.NoRelatedSymGroup(); 
msg.Header.SetField(new MsgType("V"));
msg.SetField(new MDReqID("PrimoApp123"));
msg.SetField(new SubscriptionRequestType('1'));
msg.SetField(new MarketDepth(0));
msg.SetField(new MDUpdateType(0));
// msg.SetField(new NoMDEntryTypes(2));
group.SetField(new NoMDEntryTypes(1));
msg.SetField(new MDEntryType('0'));
msg.SetField(new NoRelatedSym(1));
group.SetField(new Symbol("GBPUSD"));
//msg.SetField(new Symbol("GBPUSD"));
msg.AddGroup(group);
Session.SendToTarget(msg, FeederApp.mysession);
```

Comment: Probably the answer I've posted is gonna work. The market data request message has two repeating groups. The FIX LOG is related to repeating group issue.

Comment: Your code snippet demonstrates that you have not read the docs.  Please visit quickfixn.org and do some reading.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Trying to help. Try the code below. If it does not work please inform the FIX log file and FIX event file and any error message. Please double check if the types are OK (I used notepad) and if the compiler works.

```
// Create message instance
// If you create a specific FIX Message new QuickFix.FIX44.MarketDataRequest() instead of new Message()
// you don't need set the MessageType and your intelisense is better.
QuickFix.FIX44.MarketDataRequest msg = new QuickFix.FIX44.MarketDataRequest();

// Fill message fields
msg.SetField(new MDReqID("PrimoApp123")); 
msg.SetField(new SubscriptionRequestType('1')); 
msg.SetField(new MarketDepth(0)); 
msg.SetField(new MDUpdateType(0)); 

// Add the MDEntryTypes group
QuickFix.FIX44.MarketDataRequest.NoMDEntryTypes noMDEntryTypes = new QuickFix.FIX44.MarketDataRequest.NoMDEntryTypes();
noMDEntryTypes.SetField(new MDEntryType('0')); 
msg.addGroup(noMDEntryTypes);

// Add the NoRelatedSym group
QuickFix.FIX44.MarketDataRequest.NoRelatedSym noRelatedSym = new QuickFix.FIX44.MarketDataRequest.NoRelatedSym();
noRelatedSym.setSymbol("GBPUSD");
msg.addGroup(noRelatedSym);

// Send message
Session.SendToTarget(msg, FeederApp.mysession);
```

Comment: Thank you so much. You just saved the day. i am able to get the data now. And i assume that in fix we have to send separate request for bid and offer. is that right?

Comment: Great news!!! About your question: "separate request for bid and ask", the answer is NO, you don't need separate it. The **Repeating Group** solve this problem. Just create another instance of noMDEntryType, configure using noMDEntryType2.SetField(new MDEntryType('1')) and then msg.addGroup(noMDEntryType2);

Comment: One more help please. Any idea how i can read the coming in market data message. Because it is not hitting the fromapp() method. So where can i read the incoming messages?

Comment: @VivekJeevaKumar what is the answer to your question?

Comment: Hi. I did not see the last question in time. I would suggest to check the Session log file. The most common reason for this behavior (not reaching fromApp method) occurs when the message are being rejected in accordance to your FIX Dictionary configured. If the message is not well formatted, the quickfix engine you are using will reject the message and will not deliver to your code.

Answer (score 0):

Your message request is incorrectly assembled and the error message is telling you what. The field `371` on the reject message `35=3` is showing which tag is incorrect, and in your case is the `NoMDEntryType (267)` group.
That is occurring because you have added this group inside the `NoRelatedSym` group and not on the message.

See the code bellow for a correct created message:

```
var marketDataRequest = new MarketDataRequest();
marketDataRequest.set(new QuickFix.MDReqID(Utility.GetNewUniqueId()));
marketDataRequest.set(new QuickFix.SubscriptionRequestType('1'));
//if market depth require
marketDataRequest.set(new QuickFix.MarketDepth(1));
marketDataRequest.set(new QuickFix.MDUpdateType(1));
marketDataRequest.set(new QuickFix.AggregatedBook(true));
var noMDEntryTypes = new MarketDataRequest.NoMDEntryTypes();
var mdEntryType_bid = new QuickFix.MDEntryType('0');
noMDEntryTypes.set(mdEntryType_bid);
marketDataRequest.addGroup(noMDEntryTypes);
var mdEntryType_offer = new QuickFix.MDEntryType('1');
noMDEntryTypes.set(mdEntryType_offer);
marketDataRequest.addGroup(noMDEntryTypes);
var relatedSymbol = new MarketDataRequest.NoRelatedSym();
relatedSymbol.set(new QuickFix.Symbol(instrument));
marketDataRequest.addGroup(relatedSymbol);
//Send message
Session.sendToTarget(marketDataRequest, _admin.TradeSessionId);
```

I've got this code from [codeprojet](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/332405/Retrieve-MarketPrice-from-FixServer-using-QuickFix) and I haven´t tested it.